# Making 1 skinny column in TikZ binomial tree

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a binomial tree with arrows pointing backwards. I currently have short arrows pointing towards the left-most node (which is invisible). This first colum is taking up very little visual space, except it's pushing my `tikz` lattice to the right by a whole column's width.

How to fix?

```
     \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit,backgrounds}

    \begin{document}



       \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,sloped]
          \matrix (tree) [%
            matrix of nodes,
            minimum size=1cm,
            column sep=2.7cm,
            row sep=0.4cm,
          column 4/.style={nodes={draw,fill=cyan!30,rounded corners}},
          ]
          {
          &                    &                                               &  $^\tau S_0$     \\
          &                    &  $R^{-1}(p (_\tau S_0) + (1-p) (_\tau S_2))$  &              \\
          & ...                &                                               &  $^\tau S_1$     \\
    $  $   &                    &  $R^{-1}(p (_\tau S_1) + (1-p) (_\tau S_2))$  &              \\
          & ...                &                                               &  $^\tau S_2$     \\
          &                    &  $R^{-1}(p (_\tau S_2) + (1-p) (_\tau S_3))$  &              \\
          &                    &                                               &  $^\tau S_3$     \\
          };
          \draw[<-,shorten <=2cm,double,double distance=1pt] (tree-4-1) -- (tree-3-2) node [midway,above] {};
          \draw[<-,shorten <=2cm,double,double distance=1pt] (tree-4-1) -- (tree-5-2) node [midway,above] {};

          \draw[<-,double,double distance=1pt] (tree-3-2) -- (tree-2-3) node [midway,above] {};
          \draw[<-,double,double distance=1pt] (tree-3-2) -- (tree-4-3) node [midway,below] {};
          \draw[<-,double,double distance=1pt] (tree-5-2) -- (tree-4-3) node [midway,above] {};
          \draw[<-,double,double distance=1pt] (tree-5-2) -- (tree-6-3) node [midway,below] {};
          \draw[<-,double,double distance=1pt] (tree-2-3) -- (tree-1-4) node [midway,above] {};
          \draw[<-,double,double distance=1pt] (tree-2-3) -- (tree-3-4) node [midway,below] {};
          \draw[<-,double,double distance=1pt] (tree-4-3) -- (tree-3-4) node [midway,above] {};
          \draw[<-,double,double distance=1pt] (tree-4-3) -- (tree-5-4) node [midway,below] {};
          \draw[<-,double,double distance=1pt] (tree-6-3) -- (tree-5-4) node [midway,above] {};
          \draw[<-,double,double distance=1pt] (tree-6-3) -- (tree-7-4) node [midway,below] {};

        \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `column sep` option is valid for the first column too. So you need to override it. Also if all of your nodes involve math operators you can simply use the `matrix of math nodes` such that you don't need to use `$` signs for the entries.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit,backgrounds}

\begin{document}



   \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,sloped,mypath/.style={<-,double,double distance=1pt}]
      \matrix (tree) [%
        matrix of nodes,
        minimum size=1cm,
        column sep=2.7cm,
        row sep=0.4cm,
      column 4/.style={nodes={draw,fill=cyan!30,rounded corners}},
      column 1/.style={nodes={minimum size=3mm,inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0},column sep=3mm},
      ]
      {
      &                    &                                               &$^\tau S_0$     \\
      &                    &  $R^{-1}(p (_\tau S_0) + (1-p) (_\tau S_2))$  &              \\
      & ...                &                                               &  $^\tau S_1$     \\
$  $  &                    &  $R^{-1}(p (_\tau S_1) + (1-p) (_\tau S_2))$  &              \\
      & ...                &                                               &  $^\tau S_2$     \\
      &                    &  $R^{-1}(p (_\tau S_2) + (1-p) (_\tau S_3))$  &              \\
      &                    &                                               &  $^\tau S_3$     \\
      };
      \draw[mypath,shorten <=2mm] (tree-4-1) -- (tree-3-2) node [midway,above] {};
      \draw[mypath,shorten <=2mm] (tree-4-1) -- (tree-5-2) node [midway,above] {};

      \draw[mypath] (tree-3-2) -- (tree-2-3) node [midway,above] {};
      \draw[mypath] (tree-3-2) -- (tree-4-3) node [midway,below] {};
      \draw[mypath] (tree-5-2) -- (tree-4-3) node [midway,above] {};
      \draw[mypath] (tree-5-2) -- (tree-6-3) node [midway,below] {};
      \draw[mypath] (tree-2-3) -- (tree-1-4) node [midway,above] {};
      \draw[mypath] (tree-2-3) -- (tree-3-4) node [midway,below] {};
      \draw[mypath] (tree-4-3) -- (tree-3-4) node [midway,above] {};
      \draw[mypath] (tree-4-3) -- (tree-5-4) node [midway,below] {};
      \draw[mypath] (tree-6-3) -- (tree-5-4) node [midway,above] {};
      \draw[mypath] (tree-6-3) -- (tree-7-4) node [midway,below] {};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]